# Why Mule http inbound endpoint is always GET request

Tags: mule, inbound

Why Mule http inbound endpoint is always GET request. I'm logging type of http method 
and it always logs type is GET even I specified method type PUT in http inbound end
point.

```
 <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    path="testPath" doc:name="HTTP" 
    host="localhost" port="8083" 
    mimeType="application/json"
    method="PUT"/>

   <logger level="INFO" message="method type #[message.inboundProperties['http.method']]"
   doc:name="Logger"/>  <--- It always logs method is GET

   It never go into following expression block:

<choice doc:name="Choice">
   <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.method']=='PUT']">
```

I would like to set http method as a "PUT" in http inbound endpoint

Comment: How are you making your HTTP requests?

Comment: I'm making my http request through browser, using http://localhost:8083/testPath

Comment: So... your endpoint always receives an HTTP GET, right?

Comment: So I have a Mule-Logger afte Http-inbound endpoint. I logs http method type in that logger.Is some one need to call my Http-inbound endpoint to get correct method type? Currently I'm calling my Http-inbound endpoint through browser only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `method` attribute on `http:inbound-endpoint` is ineffective: you can put any value there, it won't change anything.

As Ale suggested, it's up to the HTTP client to use whatever method you want to receive on Mule's side.

Comment: Added following new questions about Mule publish/subscribe with Active-MQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065799/mule-publish-subscribe-model-with-active-mq-how-to-invoke-tomcat-consumers-in-a