# Mule Publish/Subscribe model with Active-MQ. How to invoke tomcat-consumers in asynchronously manner upon arriving message in Active-MQ JMS

Tags: tomcat, asynchronous, jms, mule

How I can implement JMS publish/subscribe model using Active-MQ. I have a inbound JMS Active-MQ Queue/topic where all messages are coming. On other side I've a couple of outbound Consumer(Tomcat-Http). I would like to implement a publish/Subscribe model in such a way that once I receive a message in Active-MQ it would invoke all tomcat-consumers in asynchronously manner.

Is there any way to implement above model in Mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flow for this:

```
<flow name="amq2http">
  <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="yourQueue" />
  <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://whatever.url" />
</flow>
```

Of course, you need to configure the ActiveMQ connector:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
```

Read the following links for more information:

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/ActiveMQ+Integration
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference

Comment: Perfect it works fine. is there any way to retain messages in Active-MQ queue? because if my http:outbound-endpoint(Tomcat) goes down/crash then there is no way to process that request.

Comment: Yes, in that case, you need to consume the messages transformationally in order for an HTTP error to rollback the delivery, thus trigger a subsequent redelivery. Read about reliability patterns here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Reliability+Patterns

Comment: David, Reliability is a great solution as long as you want to implement in a synchronous manner. As mentioned in a blog it only supports synchronous flow.

Comment: I want to solve my problem in asynchronous manner. I want to implement something like fire and forgot. I want to invoke/trigger http-tomcat in asynchronously.One of the solution I could think is that store message in two JMS queue, once you process message from queue-1, then delete from queue-2 as well. If any case application get crash then message still available in queue-2, we can process it. But this approach it quite expensive not much efficient. If is there any way to retain message in queue even after it get consumed then we can delete it once it get processed. Any thoughts?

Comment: In that case, wrap the HTTP endpoint with an `until-successful` element. It is async by default and will take care of the retry. This doesn't leave the message in the queue but is a Mule-provided way to perform what you want.